# Installing node-argon2 in Windows

Tags: node-gyp, argon2-ffi

**Little background**
I was trying to install `node-argon2` but having trouble installing it. I've been trying to download GCC, I already installed `node-gyp` as in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argon2) said.

*However* I keep failing on this step..

```
CXX=g++-6 npm install argon2
```

I had no idea what that function did, and this what came out when I tried to launch that in my terminal.

```
> argon2@0.21.0 install C:\Users\BizCon\Projects\express-ticket\node_modules\argon2
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\BizCon\Projects\express-ticket\node_modules\argon2>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\BizCon\Projects\express-ticket\node_modules\argon2\build\libargon2.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\BizCon\Projects\express-ticket\node_modules\argon2
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN babel-loader@8.0.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-loader@8.0.5 requires a peer of webpack@>=2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN express-server@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! argon2@0.21.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the argon2@0.21.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 2):

I was so careless at the time I asked this. I hope for whoever you are that goes to this forum have done the step on `node-gyp` repository **carefully.**

You see this is the [Installation Guide of `node-gyp` for Windows](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)

There are two options. **Just use the first one!**

> Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's
>   windows-build-tools using `npm install --global --production
>   windows-build-tools` from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as
>   Administrator).

Yes, this one `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

I was so noob at the time, I read that as '**npm install *--global--production* windows-build-tools**'. And whalaaa! I can use `node-argon2` now. HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA.

Answer (score 0):

### Before installing

You MUST have a node-gyp global install before proceeding with install, along with GCC >= 5 / Clang >= 3.3. **On Windows, you must compile under Visual Studio 2015 or newer**.

node-argon2 works only and is tested against Node >=8.0.0.

Comment: Yeah but what does that mean?